# How and why does std::bind keep pointers alive

Tags: c++, c++11

Binding a method with an object pointer and deleting the object afterwards, the method is still callable.

```
struct A {
    void b(){std::cout << "SUHDU" << std::endl;}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A *a = new A;
    auto f1 = std::bind(&A::b, a);
    auto f2 = std::bind(&A::b, std::ref(a));

    f1();
    f2();

    delete a;
    f1(); // still outputs SUHDU
    f2(); // still outputs SUHDU
}
```

Why does `std::bind` behave this way and how does it do it?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. It has nothing to do with `std::bind`, really.

Comment: @chris So it's just un-reallocated memory.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478262/c-why-i-can-access-member-functions-even-after-the-object-was-deleted)

Comment: As it is undefined behavior it isn't guaranteed that you can make it fail but you could have the destructor of your `A` object set a pointer to null which used by `b()`: most likely this would cause a crash. For example, `struct A { std::ostream* out; A(): out(&std::cout) {} ~A() { out = 0; } void b() { *(this->out) << "hello\n"; } };`. Your example didn't really access anything from `A`, i.e., there is no reason the function needs to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour. It stores a copy of the argument, in your case the `A*` which is later on invalid. This hint also leads to the fix: To make your example legal, use `std::shared_ptr`:

```
struct A {
    void b(){std::cout << "SUHDU" << std::endl;}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto f1 = std::bind(&A::b, a);

    f1();

    a.reset();

    f1(); // still outputs SUHDU
}
```

Of course, this will keep your object alive until `f1` goes out of scope.